# How to get Position of an view added dynamically on LinearLayout

Tags: android

I need to get an dynamically added view position in LinearLayout with vertical orientation.
For example i have 4 TextViews added dynamically on LinearLayout, then i need to change position of text colour at 3rd position will be in different color.How can i achieve it by getting position of added views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it just like that

```
ViewGroup parent;
    int position;

    for(int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); ++i) {
        int currentViewId = parent.getChildAt(i).getId();

        if(currentViewId == wantendViewId) {
            position = i;
        }
    }
```

That's (in my opinion) the simplest way

Answer (score 0):

If you always know the number of TextViews in your LinearLayout, you can just use the function `getChildAt( int position )`. This returns a `View` which you can then cast to a `TextView` to be able to perform the desired operations.

If you do not know the number of elements you could set the id of each TextView (in order to be able to identify a particular one) and then run through them like this:

```
for( View view : myLinearLayout )
  if( view instanceof TextView && view.getId().equals( idToSearchFor ) )
    //Do what needs to be done.
```

Answer (score 0):

I see following options:

- Declare some id's in resources in form of `<item type="id">first</item>` and assign them to
  views in adding to layout, after that use normal `findViewById()` mechanism
- Assign some tags to views you're adding to a layout via `setTag` method and after that use `findViewWithTag` mechanism
- Remeber position of your views and use them vie `getChildAt` method

Answer (score 0):

I got simple option.

suppose you add

View v;//any view

linearlayout.addview(v);//add in layout

While u want to modify view.

simpaly remove old view.

linearlayout.removeView(v);

add new update view object

v-updated new view

linearlayout.addview(v);