# How to Automatic divided 2 child view, if they overlap?

Tags: android

Can someone answer me, how to automatic divided 2 view child in 1 layout if it's overlap?? ex: Relatativelayout have 2 button and it's overlap,if  i add view child by programmatically add this button 1 -> this width is full ralative, add button 2 if this overlap on button 1-> it's will divided 50% for button 1 and 50% for button 2 of relativedLayout, contrary do nothing? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

you could use , `addView(View v, int position)` to avoid overlapping

where the position is the position of the new child.

Comment: So how to know it overlap?

Comment: have a look here, there is no strict way to do this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737148/how-to-get-position-of-an-view-added-dynamically-on-linearlayout, why you don't use LinearLayout instead of relativeLayout?